# free() complains about invalid pointer

Tags: c, string, printf, concatenation

I'm trying to build a string piece by piece in my program by concatenating some values in order to obtain something like :

```
|0x0F64:0x0063:0x1A|0x7CC4:0x0073:0x1A|0x0A51:0xA29A:0x9C|0xD49D:0x0058:0x10|
```

I would like to use a dynamic variable because the NB_ELEMENT might be improved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NB_ELEMENT 4
typedef struct
{
   unsigned short  u16Val1;
   unsigned short  u16Val2;
   unsigned char   u8Val3;
}stElement;

stElement element[NB_ELEMENT] = {{ 0 }};

int main()
{
    element[0].u16Val1 = 3940;
    element[0].u16Val2 = 99;
    element[0].u8Val3 = 26; 

    element[1].u16Val1 = 31940;
    element[1].u16Val2 = 115;
    element[2].u8Val3 = 26;           

    element[2].u16Val1 = 2641;
    element[2].u16Val2 = 41620;
    element[2].u8Val3 = 156; 

    element[3].u16Val1 = 52429;
    element[3].u16Val2 = 88;
    element[3].u8Val3 = 16;

    char *str = malloc(NB_ELEMENT * sizeof element);

    snprintf(str, sizeof element, "|0x%04x:0x%04x:0x%x\n",element[0].u16Val1,
                                                      element[0].u16Val2,
                                                      element[0].u8Val3);

    str += sprintf(str, "|0x%04x:0x%04x:0x%x\n",element[1].u16Val1,
                                            element[1].u16Val2,
                                            element[1].u8Val3);

    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above returns :

```
*** Error in `./TEST': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000cac023 ***
```

However, I managed to print `|0x0f64:0x0063:0x1a` but avec adding  str += sprintf.., the error occurs.

Comment: Man, in C `str += ` is not concatenation, it is incrementing a pointer. Concatenation of strings in C needs two buffer (from and to) and the function `strcat`.

Comment: Other issue: In `char *str = malloc(NB_ELEMENT * sizeof element);`, tell me how `NB_ELEMENT * sizeof element` relates to the size of the string you are creating?

Comment: Should use something like `size = ...; char *str = malloc(size); int n = snprintf(str, size, ...); if (n < 0 || n >= size) Error();`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is here:

```
str += sprintf(str, "|0x%04x:0x%04x:0x%x\n",element[1].u16Val1,
                                        element[1].u16Val2,
                                        element[1].u8Val3);
```

That **modifies** the pointer in `str`. So when you hand it to `free` later, it's not the same pointer that `malloc` gave you, which makes `free`'s job rather difficult.

Solution: Don't modify the pointer. If you want to keep track of where you are in the buffer by adding the number of characters written to the pointer, use a *different* pointer for that:

```
char *str = malloc(NB_ELEMENT * sizeof element);
// ...
char * p = str;
// ...
p += sprintf(p, "|0x%04x:0x%04x:0x%x\n",element[1].u16Val1,
                                        element[1].u16Val2,
                                        element[1].u8Val3);
// ...
free(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not passing `free()` the same pointer returned by `malloc()`. So, [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With this statement:

```
 str += sprintf(str, "|0x%04x:0x%04x:0x%x\n",element[1].u16Val1,
                                             element[1].u16Val2,
                                             element[1].u8Val3);
```

You have changed`str`.

From [`free()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html):

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which
>   **must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc(), or realloc()**.  Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called
>   before, undefined behavior occurs.  If ptr is NULL, no operation is
>   performed.

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate strings in this way in C.

```
str += something
```

just changes the address stored in `str` to something else, which then makes it an invalid pointer to be freed (since it's a value not obtained from `malloc`/`calloc` anymore).

You should use [`strncat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncat) if you want to concatenate string, by initially allocate a buffer which is large enough to fit the whole contents.

Comment: He's not concatenating, since `sprintf()` doesn't return a string. It returns the number of characters printed, so that `str` now points to the next place in the buffer to print at.

Answer (score 2):

```
 man 3 free
```

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, **which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc()  or
>          realloc()**.   Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs.

Since your `str` is a pointer obtained by adding a number to a pointer obtained from `malloc()`, it doesn't meet this requirement, and undefined behaviour results.

Be grateful it's a hard failure on your system -- on some systems it would have resulted in a memory leak or in weird memory corruption that would only reveal itself when your program started producing garbage.

Your code has other problems. You should probably review your C book's chapter on pointers and strings.